# Swift Initializing class with parametres then initialize it without parametres

Tags: json, swift, class, initialization

I have function which initialize class from json and send values with sending parametres from text fields of view controller. And i should show values of this class in another view controller without sending params. This  is my code

```
Alamofire.request(url!, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
    if response.data != nil {
        switch response.result
        {
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            guard let dataarr = json["my_profile"].arrayObject as? [String] else {return}
            if dataarr.count > 0 {
                teacherinfo.name = dataarr[0]
                teacherinfo.surname = dataarr[1]
                teacherinfo.email = dataarr[2]
                teacherinfo.phone = dataarr[3]
                completion(teacherinfo,true)
            }
            else
            {
                completion(teacherinfo,false)
            }
        }
    }
})
```

This is my class

```
class TeacherInfo {
    var name : String = ""
    var surname : String = ""
    var email : String = ""
    var phone : String = ""
}
```

Here I initialize it

```
func search2() {
    TeacherSearcher.SearchTeachers(name: about.nametextfield.text!, surname: about.surnametextfiel.text!) { (teacherinfo,success) in
        if success! {
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(TeacherViewController(), animated: true)
        }
        else {
            print("not")
        }
    }
}
```

I should return values of class without initializing params

Comment: is it you want to pass class **TeacherInfo** to your **TeacherViewController** ?

Comment: I pass data to TeacherInfo from TeacherViewController , and i want to show data of Teachers without passing data in the another ViewController

Comment: use **Structs**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create a Struct**

```
struct TeacherInfo {
    static var name : String = ""
    static var surname : String = ""
    static var email : String = ""
    static var phone : String = ""
}
```

**Pass data**

```
/// Save Data in Struct
/// Now this struct is Accessible in all your controllers
/// Without passing any Object in it
TeacherInfo.email = "Teacher Email"
TeacherInfo.name = "iOS"
TeacherInfo.surname = "Geek"
TeacherInfo.phone = "123456789"

/// Destination VC
print(TeacherInfo.email)
print(TeacherInfo.name)
print(TeacherInfo.surname)
print(TeacherInfo.phone)
```

**Note** This way you can pass data from one VC to another VC without initialising class

Answer (score 0):

```
struct TeacherInfo {
static var name : String!
static var surname : String!
static var email : String!
static var phone : String!

init(name:String, surname:String, email:String, phone:String) {
    self.name = name
    self.surname = surname
    self.email = email
    self.phone = phone
    }
}
```

--

```
if dataarr.count > 0 {
            let element = TeacherInfo(name:dataarr[0], surname:dataarr[1], email:dataarr[2], phone:dataarr[3])
            completion(teacherinfo,true)
        }
```